# How to manage Docker server by multi clients

Tags: docker, boot2docker, vsphere

I want to implement Docker for my project.

Now, my project has an enterprise server (Redhat 6) which is running ESXi. We created many developer accounts and set permissions for them. Our developers use the vSphere Client to manage the virtual machines.

[image: VMware vSphere]
<sub>(source: [vmware.com](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/topic/com.vmware.vsphere.solutions.doc_50/GUID-0D374C9A-969E-4393-9045-87B36A479E11-low.png))</sub>

We can install the Docker on the server. But how to provide the developers account so that they can access the server via their machine? I mean that the developers could manage their dockers by a client. Could we implement a similar workflow like VMware?

- Server: which software to manage Docker users account?
- Client: which software to connect the Docker server?

Comment: Docker machine reportedly supports vSphere: http://blogs.vmware.com/cloudnative/docker-machine-deployment-vm-fusion-vsphere-vcloud-air/

Comment: Thanks Mark. But it's still in preview period...

Comment: Shipyard might be the right one.

Comment: Rancher is another project worth looking at.

Comment: Thanks, rancher has a lot of features.